# how to ignore 2 users with same id and just print the first user?

Tags: java

I'm making a group class in java but I have a problem that If the user tries to do an operation that could violate the state of objects, I don't know how to ignore the operation
and make the application display an error message

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Group {
    private static int staticNumber = 0;
    private int groupNumber;
    private Trainer trainer;
    private String sportName;
    private ArrayList<Kid> kids;
    private final static int MAX_LIMIT = 10;

    public Group(Trainer t, String sport) {
        groupNumber = staticNumber++;
        this.trainer = t;
        this.sportName = sport;
        kids = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static int getStaticNumber() {
        return staticNumber;
    }

    public int getGroupNumber() {
        return groupNumber;
    }

    public Trainer getTrainer() {
        return trainer;
    }

    public String getSportName() {
        return sportName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Kid> getKids() {
        return kids;
    }

    public boolean addKid(Kid k) {
        if (kids.size() < MAX_LIMIT) {
            kids.add(k);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean removeKid(Kid k) {
        return kids.remove(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: You **already** ignore the operation in `addKid` when the size is >= the limit. What's the difference here?

Comment: I ignore it yeah but don't know how to print error when this happens so if this happens the program prints for example "User wasn't Added Try again " or something

Comment: Then do the ignoring part first and once you've verified that this works, maybe update your question to be *more specific*.

Comment: Thank you and maybe i wasn't clear enough in my post xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a println() before the return will output the message in console:

```
public boolean addKid(Kid k) {
        if (kids.size() < MAX_LIMIT) {
            kids.add(k);
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("User wasn't Added Try again");
            return false;
            
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, if you would like to throw an exception, which would terminate your run of the code:

```
public boolean addKid(Kid k) {
        if (kids.size() < MAX_LIMIT) {
            kids.add(k);
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Too many Kids");
        }
    }
```

Hope this helped!